# Android - How do I get a specific ID from an ImageButton array?

Tags: android, arrays, imagebutton

I'm making an App using lots of click-able ImageButtons (116 to be precise). And there is my question already: How can I declare all Buttons in one loop? Also, all the Buttons lead to the same View, but I need the ID of the Button clicked on it.
Here is what I've got:

```
public void addListenerOnImageButtons() {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 116; i++) {
        final Context context = this;
        String buttonID = "imgbutton_"+i;
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID,"id",getPackageName());
        imageButton[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(resID);
        imageButton[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My Buttons are called "imgbutton_1", "imgbutton_2", ... ,"imgbutton_116" and are declared in the file "detail_layout.xml".
Of course I could go throu every Button, but I believe there is a more elegant solution :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use an `HashMap<Integer, ImageButton> map = new HashMap<Integer, ImageButton>();`  and use the id as key

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 116; i++) {
        final Context context = this;
        String buttonID = "imgbutton_"+i;
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID,"id",getPackageName());
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(resID);
        map.put(resID, imageButto);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);   
            }
        });
    }
```